# How to group by 24 hours in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

So, I have traffic counts done over 48-hour periods and I want to group these by 24-hour day counts.

ie Sept 30 at 11am - Oct 2 at 10am. The first "Day" would be from Sept 30, 11am to Oct. 1, 10am. The second "Day" would be from Oct. 1, 11am to Oct 2, 10am.
input:

```
timestamp               Count
----------              ------
2020-09-30, 11:00:00    5
2020-09-30, 12:00:00    3
2020-09-30, 13:00:00    5
2020-09-30, 14:00:00    7
2020-10-01, 10:00:00    2
2020-10-01, 11:00:00    8
2020-10-01, 12:00:00    12
2020-10-01, 13:00:00    7
2020-10-01, 14:00:00    4
2020-10-02, 10:00:00    9
```

expected:

```
interval                                       Sum(count)
----------                                     ------
 2020-09-30, 11:00:00 - 2020-10-01, 10:00:00     22
 2020-10-01, 11:00:00 - 2020-10-02, 10:00:00     40
```

As you can see, there are three separate calendar days in this example, so I can't just group by day. Is there a decent way to group my data like this?

Maybe I should also note, that there would not simply be 48 records in this example. There are records for each lane (shown in another field) for each hour interval.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is data in Access table? Is it a date/time or text field?

Comment: Sorry, I should specify: Right now, I actually have the date in a Date/Time field and the hour in a number field. But I can always change that. It was just the best way for my purpose at the time. Everything is in an Access table.

Comment: Should edit question with that info and show actual table structure.

Comment: _Sorry, the 11 am starting time was just an example_ ... and with non-defined or varying parameters, you make it quite difficult.

Comment: Okay. Assume I'm going to fix the date/time
The timestamp is a date/time, the count is a number
The count periods can start at any time but always run for 48 hour periods. I would like the first 24 hours grouped, and the second 24 hours grouped separately. I would like the count summed.
Hopefully that is everything. Sorry for being difficult...

Comment: Thanks. But for a 24-hour period, how to determine if it belongs to the last part of a 48-hour period or the first part?

Answer (score 1):

Consider normalizing the timestamps with a host of conversion functions (`DATEVALUE` + `CSTR` + `CDATE`) for a grouping column that can be used in an aggregate query. Essentially, you subtract 11 hours from all datetimes (due to 11:00 AM start) then strip out the time component.

```sql
SELECT MIN(CDATE(h.[timestamp] + (h.[hour]/24) )) 
       & ' - ' &
       MAX(CDATE(h.[timestamp] + (h.[hour]/24) )) AS [INTERVAL]
     , SUM(h.[count]) AS [SUM_Count]
FROM HourGroupTimeStamps h
GROUP BY DATEVALUE(CSTR(CDATE(h.[timestamp] + (h.[hour]/24) - (11/24) )))
```

Input Table

[image: Input Table]

Output Query

[image: Output Query]

Comment: Sorry, the 11 am starting time was just an example for that count. Other counts will have various starting times.
If there is some way to get the minimum date/time and subtract that hour it could work. But I don't know enough about compound queries to figure that out.
I should normalize my time stamps and I'll do that probably before I build this query.

Comment: Ok. Then, use domain aggregate, `DMIN`. Specifically, in `GROUP BY` replace `11/24` with `(DMIN("hour", "myTable")/24)`

Comment: Ah! I didn't know about DMIN. That sounds like the correct thing to do. Thanks!